# Как упростить? Ввод слов и сортировка по гласным JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Я хотела выполнить задание и написать код, который принимает на вход слова, а выводит предложение, где отсортированы слова по кол-ву гласных.
У меня вышло на JavaScript достаточно громоздко.
Можно ли упростить и написать функцией?

```
let number = prompt('Введите количество слов (n): ');
number = Number(number.trim());


let arrWord = [];       // пустой массив для введеных слов

for (let i = 1; i <= number; i += 1) {
    let word = prompt(`Введите слово №${i}: `);
    word = word.trim();
    
    arrWord.push(word); // Добавить значение в конец
}

arrWord.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.toLowerCase().match(/[ауоыиэяюёеaeiouy]/g) 
      > b.toLowerCase().match(/[ауоыиэяюёеaeiouy]/g)) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.toLowerCase().match(/[ауоыиэяюёеaeiouy]/g) 
    < b.toLowerCase().match(/[ауоыиэяюёеaeiouy]/g)) {
    return -1;
  }
  // a должно быть равным b
  return 0;
});

alert(arrWord.join(" "));   //Метод Array.join() преобразует все элементы массива в строки
```

Comment: у тебя не сортируются слова по количеству гласных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В javaScript можно практически все описать через функцию :)
Код сокращается переносом .trim() в момент считывания данных из prompt а так же удалением дублирующего кода и выносом его в функцию match()

```js
function match(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().match(/[ауоыиэяюёеaeiouy]/g)?.length || 0;
}

function sorterLetters() {
  const number = Number(prompt('Введите количество слов (n): ').trim());
  const arrWord = [];       // пустой массив для введеных слов

  for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    arrWord.push(prompt(`Введите слово №${i}: `).trim()); // Добавить значение в конец
  }

  arrWord.sort(function(a, b) {
    return match(a) - match(b)
  });

  //alert(arrWord.join(" "));   //Метод Array.join() преобразует все элементы массива в строки
  return arrWord;
}

console.log(sorterLetters());
```

Comment: `match(a) - match(b)` - не надо так делать. `match` возвращает массив. Применение `-` к массивам может давать неожиданные результаты.

Comment: @Grundy Что то я проморгал этот момент. Поправил

Comment: если не будет совпадений `match` вернет `null`

Comment: @Grundy Поправил, будет возвращать 0