# Пытался сделать счетчик, который обрабатывает два массива, нужно было найти кол-во слов у которых всего 2 или меньше - гласных букв (я только учусь)

Tags: javascript

```
let arrOfNames = ["Василий", "Маша", "Дима", "Андрей", "Юля", "Саша", "Антон", "Тимур", "Света"]
let arrofVowels = ["а", "и", "е", "ю", "о", "я"]
function ob() {
    let vcount = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < arrOfNames.length; i++) {
        let rcount = 0
        for (let j = 0; j < arrofVowels.length; j++) {
            if (arrOfNames[i].indexOf(arrofVowels[j]) >= 1){
                rcount++
            }
        }
        if (rcount < 3){
            vcount++

        } else {
            return console.log("1")
        }
    }
    return vcount
}
console.log(ob())
```

Comment: Если учесть, что обычных слов не бывает совсем без гласных, то: 
`let found = arrOfNames.filter(word => word.match(/[аеёиоуыэюя]/ig)?.length <= 2);`

Comment: Вот тут решали такую же задачу, только еще с сортировкой по количеству гласных [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460799/](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460799/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%92%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-javascript/1460803#1460803)